# How to write a testthat unit test for a function that returns a data frame

Tags: r, unit-testing, testthat

I am writing a script that ultimately returns a data frame. My question is around if there are any good practices on how to use a unit test package to make sure that the data frame that is returned is correct. (I'm a beginning R programmer, plus new to the concept of unit testing)

My script effectively looks like the following:

```
# initialize data frame
df.out <- data.frame(...)

# function set
function1 <- function(x) {...}
function2 <- function(x) {...}

# do something to this data frame
df.out$new.column <- function1(df.out)

# do something else
df.out$other.new.column <- function2(df.out)

# etc ....
```

... and I ultimately end up with a data frame with many new columns. However, what is the best approach to test that the data frame that is produced is what is anticipated, using unit tests?

So far I have created unit tests that check the results of each function, but I want to make sure that running all of these together produces what is intended. I've looked at [Hadley Wickham's page on testing](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/tests.html) but can't see anything obvious regarding what to do when returning data frames.

My thoughts to date are:

- Create an expected data frame by hand
- Check that the output equals this data frame, using `expect_that` or similar

Any thoughts / pointers on where to look for guidance? My Google-fu has let me down considerably on this one to date.

Comment: Like [this](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/tests/testthat/test-colwise.R)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your intuition seems correct. Construct a data.frame manually based on the expected output of the function and then compare that against the function's output.

```
# manually created data
dat <- iris[1:5, c("Species", "Sepal.Length")]

# function
myfun <- function(row, col, data) {
    data[row, col]
}

# result of applying function
outdat <- myfun(1:5, c("Species", "Sepal.Length"), iris)

# two versions of the same test
expect_true(identical(dat, outdat))
expect_identical(dat, outdat)
```

If your data.frame may not be *identical*, you could also run tests in parts of the data.frame, including:

- `dim(outdat)`, to check if the size is correct
- `attributes(outdat)` or attributes of columns
- `sapply(outdat, class)`, to check variable classes
- summary statistics for variables, if applicable
- and so forth

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to test this at runtime, you should check out the excellent `ensurer` package, see [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ensurer/vignettes/ensurer.html). At the bottom of the page you can see how to construct a template that you can test your dataframe against, you can make it as detailed and specific as you like.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just using something like this

```
d1 <- iris
d2 <- iris 
expect_that(d1, equals(d2)) # passes
d3 <- iris
d3[141,3] <- 5
expect_that(d1, equals(d3)) # fails
```